# Python error reading directory?

Tags: python

I have the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import glob, os

os.chdir("/data")
for file in glob.glob("*.gz"):
    print(file)
```

When I run this script I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.chdir("/data")
```

Comment: The error message is missing at the end. E.g. I get "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data'" if there is no /data directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have permission to your `/data` directory. Also check if it isn't in your home directory.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but now I get error: `File "python.py", line 7
    with open(file) as fd:
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: That's an syntax error. You have not done the indentation right in your code

Comment: You've probably mixed tabs and spaces in your code.